# Can I make text of an element (complexType and mixed) mandatory through XSD and one attribute mandatory based on enumeration

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this XML

```
<button onclick="alert('submit')" replace="append" forid="loginbutton" id="btnLogin" >Click Me</button>
```

And I have this XSD

```
  <xs:element name="button" >
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                <xs:attribute name="forid" use="required" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="onclick" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute name="replace" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="modify" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="append" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I want two things here

1. The button content text should be mandatory in all cases
2. If the value of `replace` attribute is *'append'* then attribute `id` will be mandatory

Answer (score 3):

If you make this a complex-type-with-simple-content, then you can constrain the permitted values of the text using xs:enumeration. If you make it a complex-type-with-mixed-content, then you can't constrain what goes in the text. It seems to me you want simple content here, not mixed content (there are no child elements).

You can't define a co-constraint (values of one thing dependent on the values of another) using XSD 1.0 - for that you need XSD 1.1. Support for XSD 1.1 is currently available only in Saxon and Xerces.

Comment: I cannot use enumeration to define the content text. It can be any value, may be a length of at least 1 character will be right constraint or some not null constraint. Second thing can you give some snippets regarding dependent attribute being mandatory based one some selected value in the first attribute(replace).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done somehow. I quite did not understand it, basically I just did trial and error. If someone can explain what this means I will be grateful.

```
<xs:element name="button">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1" />

                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:attribute name="forid" use="required" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="onclick" />
                <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="replace" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="modify" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="append" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>

            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: This schema satisfies your first requirement that the text content is mandatory. It doesn't satisfy your second requirement that the id attribute is mandatory when replace="append".